# jQuery Perfect Scroll - Set Scrollbar to the Bottom of the Container

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have just installed perfect scroll, the jQuery plugin, and it works great but I can't find a parameter to start the content at the bottom of my div.  I want to have to scroll up on page load, not to have to scroll down.

Normally with jQuery I would just do:

```
$(nav_message_list).prop({ scrollTop: $(nav_message_list).prop("scrollHeight")});
```

But that seems to have no effect.

Current code:

```
$(".chat_person").click(function ()
                         {
                          if (!$(".chat_content_wrap").is(":visible"))
                           {  
                            $(".chat_content_wrap").fadeIn(300, function ()   
                                                                 {
                                                                  $('#message_list').perfectScrollbar('update');
                                                                  $(nav_message_list).prop({ scrollTop: $(nav_message_list).prop("scrollHeight")});
                                                                 });
                           }
                          });

$("#message_list").perfectScrollbar();
```

Comment: show some html or can you set fiddle

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418087/jquery-perfect-scroll-set-scrollbar-to-the-bottom-of-the-container/19418474#19418474 this.. Me too using this only...

Answer (score 17):

I haven't used the plugin before but based on the docs at https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar

The code you should need is:

```
$("#message_list").scrollTop( $( "#message_list" ).prop( "scrollHeight" ) );
$("#message_list").perfectScrollbar('update');
```

The $ selectors may be wrong since I can't see you HTML code.

Comment: November 2021: This still works. Thank you :)

Answer (score -4):

**Scrooltop**

paste below JavaScript code just before `</head>` code.

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

paste below JavaScript code just  `<body>` code.

```
    <div class="scrool">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/ikeq9mi/DfYl6o46t/scrolltotop.min.js"></script>
    <a href="javascript:;" id="scrollToTop" rel="nofollow" title="Go to Top"><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/cqpvki8/7yWlh05zn/seta.png" title="Go to Top" alt="Go to Top"/></a>
</div>
```

Now on the Customize page, Go and Hit the button “Edit HTML” and add below css codes just before

```
#scrollToTop:link, 
#scrollToTop:visited {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}
```

For reference http://www.tumblings.net/post/38379026809/scrolltotopbuttoncode
Use this code